# Go template merging dictionary with a possibly empty source dictionary

Tags: go-templates

In a go template I'm merging labels from project level and application level with

```
{{ range $k, $v := (merge $project.labels $app.labels) }}
  # Do something with $k and $v.
{{end}}
```

Both `$project.labels` and `$app.labels` are dictionaries generated from a yaml file.
Now I want to make `app.labels` as an optional field, this can be done with some extra `with` statement but I wonder if there is an elegant way to do this.

Currently if `$app.label` is not defined in the yaml file I'll get:

`wrong type for value; expected map[string]interface {}; got interface {}`

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out by adding empty dict as a default:

`{{ range $k, $v := (merge $project.labels ($app.labels | default dict)) }}`